# Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil)

Tags: c, mpi

> I am trying to calculate the sum of an array **A** using the reduce command; note here that **A** is only visible to the master node/root (0).

I am getting the following error and I can't seem to figure out why. Also, broadcasting the part (**N**) still produces the same error.

**Error:**

```sh
[kali:74924:0:74924] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
==== backtrace (tid:  74924) ====
 0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x2dc) [0x7f14b5486a9c]
 1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28c8f) [0x7f14b5486c8f]
 2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28e4a) [0x7f14b5486e4a]
 3  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3c910) [0x7f14b564e910]
 4  ./parts(+0x14f1) [0x557de43984f1]
 5  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xcd) [0x7f14b56397ed]
 6  ./parts(+0x113a) [0x557de439813a]
=================================
[kali:74925:0:74925] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
==== backtrace (tid:  74925) ====
 0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x2dc) [0x7fb3324b0a9c]
 1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28c8f) [0x7fb3324b0c8f]
 2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28e4a) [0x7fb3324b0e4a]
 3  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3c910) [0x7fb332678910]
 4  ./parts(+0x14f1) [0x5581e42d44f1]
 5  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xcd) [0x7fb3326637ed]
 6  ./parts(+0x113a) [0x5581e42d413a]
=================================
[kali:74926:0:74926] Caught signal 11 (Segmentation fault: address not mapped to object at address (nil))
==== backtrace (tid:  74926) ====
 0  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(ucs_handle_error+0x2dc) [0x7f7e8e8f9a9c]
 1  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28c8f) [0x7f7e8e8f9c8f]
 2  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libucs.so.0(+0x28e4a) [0x7f7e8e8f9e4a]
 3  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(+0x3c910) [0x7f7e8eac1910]
 4  ./parts(+0x14f1) [0x558b09e094f1]
 5  /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xcd) [0x7f7e8eaac7ed]
 6  ./parts(+0x113a) [0x558b09e0913a]
=================================

===================================================================================
=   BAD TERMINATION OF ONE OF YOUR APPLICATION PROCESSES
=   PID 74924 RUNNING AT kali
=   EXIT CODE: 11
=   CLEANING UP REMAINING PROCESSES
=   YOU CAN IGNORE THE BELOW CLEANUP MESSAGES
===================================================================================
YOUR APPLICATION TERMINATED WITH THE EXIT STRING: Segmentation fault (signal 11)
This typically refers to a problem with your application.
Please see the FAQ page for debugging suggestions
```

**Codes:**

w/out broadcast

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank;
    int size;
    int sum = 0;
    int grand_sum = 0;
    int i;
    int *A;
    int N;
    int part;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0) {
        do {
            printf("Enter the array size: ");
            scanf("%d", &N);
        } while (N <= 0);

        A = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if (!A) {
            printf("Array too big!\nExiting the program...\n");
            return -1;
        }

        part = N / size;

        srand(10);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            grand_sum += A[i];
            printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
        }
        
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            MPI_Send(&part, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&A[i * part], part, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    } else {
        int part;
        MPI_Recv(&part, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        int Aw[part];
        MPI_Recv(&Aw, part, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&sum, &grand_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (i = size * part; i < N; i++) {
            grand_sum += A[i];
        }

        printf("\nThe grand sum is: %d", grand_sum);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

*w/broadcast*

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <mpi.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int main (int argc, char** argv) {
    int rank;
    int size;
    int sum = 0;
    int grand_sum = 0;
    int i;
    int *A;
    int N;
    int part;

    MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);
    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &size);

    if (rank == 0) {
        do {
            printf("Enter the array size: ");
            scanf("%d", &N);
        } while (N <= 0);

        A = malloc(N * sizeof(int));
        if (!A) {
            printf("Array too big!\nExiting the program...\n");
            return -1;
        }

        part = N / size;

        srand(10);
        for (i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            A[i] = rand() % 10 + 1;
            printf("A[%d] = %d\n", i, A[i]);
        }
        
        for (i = 1; i < size; i++) {
            //MPI_Send(&part, 1, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
            MPI_Send(&A[i * part], part, MPI_INT, i, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);
        }
    } 
    
    MPI_Bcast(&part, 1, MPI_INT, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank != 0) {
        //MPI_Recv(&part, 1, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);
        int Aw[part];
        MPI_Recv(&Aw, part, MPI_INT, 0, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD, MPI_STATUS_IGNORE);

        for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
            sum += A[i];
        }
    }

    MPI_Reduce(&sum, &grand_sum, 1, MPI_INT, MPI_SUM, 0, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

    if (rank == 0) {
        for (i = size * part; i < N; i++) {
            grand_sum += A[i];
        }

        printf("\nThe grand sum is: %d", grand_sum);
    }

    MPI_Finalize();
}
```

Comment: Why is there two snippets? Which one gives the error? Where's the necessary data to run it? Would be nice if your traces had line numbers. Are you compiling with symbols?

Comment: Both give the same error, it was my attempt trying to make the code work. The data (array elements) is based on the rand function. The program was compiled with the command ```mpicc parts.c -o parts```, and run with ```mpirun -n 4 ./parts```.

Comment: Ok, there aren't as many inputs as I thought, but there is still one: `scanf("%d", &N);`. And the last sentence wasn't really a question unless the answer was yes. It was something to do.

Comment: I have tried entering many values (5, 15, 200, ...); the elements get printed, but the error persists.

Comment: Got similar error on nullptr access :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After rereading my code, I've spotted a mistake at the `for` loop, of the `else` statement:

```c
for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
            sum += A[i];
}
```

**A** is not visible here; thus the error. **Aw** should have been used here instead.

Correct code:

```c
for (i = 0; i < part; i++) {
            sum += Aw[i];
}
```

Comment: You need to install valgrind. That would catch such memory errors.